# LDAP mocking in Python (ldap3 module)

Tags: python, mocking, ldap

My current task is to do QA Automation on our web app, but I don't want to use real credentials for it (for which we use a LDAP server). My idea was to mock the LDAP server when the web app is in TEST_MODE, and to my luck I found out that 'ldap3' (the python module) that we use for authentication, also supports a mocking function. An example code is here:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, ALL_ATTRIBUTES, MOCK_SYNC
REAL_SERVER = 'my_real_server'
REAL_USER = 'cn=my_real_user,ou=test,o=lab'
REAL_PASSWORD = 'my_real_password'

# Retrieve server info and schema from a real server
server = Server(REAL_SERVER, get_info=ALL)
connection = Connection(server, REAL_USER, REAL_PASSWORD, auto_bind=True)

# Store server info and schema to json files
server.info.to_file('my_real_server_info.json')
server.schema.to_file('my_real_server_schema.json')

# Read entries from a portion of the DIT from real server and store them in a json file
if connection.search('ou=test,o=lab', '(objectclass=*)', attributes=ALL_ATTRIBUTES):
    connection.response_to_file('my_real_server_entries.json', raw=True)

# Close the connection to the real server
connection.unbind()

# Create a fake server from the info and schema json files
fake_server = Server.from_definition('my_fake_server', 'my_real_server_info.json', 'my_real_server_schema.json')

# Create a MockSyncStrategy connection to the fake server
fake_connection = Connection(fake_server, user='cn=my_user,ou=test,o=lab', password='my_password', client_strategy=MOCK_SYNC)

# Populate the DIT of the fake server
fake_connection.strategy.entries_from_json('my_real_server_entries.json')

# Add a fake user for Simple binding
fake_connection.strategy.add_entry('cn=my_user,ou=test,o=lab', {'userPassword': 'my_password', 'sn': 'user_sn', 'revision': 0})

# Bind to the fake server
fake_connection.bind()
```

I followed this example with our code, and was successful halfway through it. I extracted the real_server_entries in a json file, and now is part to do the fake connection. So to summarise everything is done until this part:

```
# Create a MockSyncStrategy connection to the fake server
    fake_connection = Connection(fake_server, user='cn=my_user,ou=test,o=lab', password='my_password', client_strategy=MOCK_SYNC)
```

I am not really sure what to put in the place of `user` and `password`.

A part of my code:

```
_USER_SEARCH_FILTER = "(&(objectClass=user)(cn={}))"
_ALL_USERS_SEARCH_FILTER = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"
_EMAIL_ATTRIBUTE = "mail"
_DISPLAY_NAME_ATTRIBUTE = "displayName"
_USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE = "cn"
_SEARCH_ATTRIBUTES = (
    _EMAIL_ATTRIBUTE, _DISPLAY_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, _USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE)

_LDAP_CONNECTION_ERROR = "Connection to LDAP server %s:%s failed: %s"

_LDAP_SERVER = Server(host=LDAP.host, port=int(LDAP.port), get_info='ALL')

server = _LDAP_SERVER

_CONNECTION = Connection(
    server,
    LDAP.manager_dn, LDAP.manager_password,
    auto_bind=True, client_strategy=RESTARTABLE
)

server.info.to_file('my_real_server_info.json')
server.schema.to_file('my_real_server_schema.json')

if _CONNECTION.search(LDAP.root_dn, _ALL_USERS_SEARCH_FILTER, attributes=_SEARCH_ATTRIBUTES):
    _CONNECTION.response_to_file('my_real_server_entries.json', raw=True)

_CONNECTION.unbind()

mock_server = Server.from_definition('mock_server', 'my_real_server_info.json', 'my_real_server_schema.json')

mock_connection = Connection(mock_server, user='???', password='???', client_strategy=MOCK_SYNC)

mock_connection.strategy.entries_from_json('my_real_server_entries.json')

mock_connection.strategy.add_entry('LDAP.root_dn', { #My guess is that here I mock the attributes, but this is also the other problem I am having (check below) })
```

The other problem I have is that I am not even sure if I can add a fake user, because when I took a look into the `real_entries.json` file the password is not stored there as an attribute (not even an encrypted version of it) and the only attributes we have are:

```
`cn` - username
`displayName` - LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME
`mail` - example@mail.com
```

Comment: I have the identical problem.   Anyone or @cannatag, the ldap3 maintainer, have a soln?